# I cannot get this code to output the average pay rate, can anyone explain why?

Tags: c++, logic

Why isn't this code able to output the average pay rate? Is it because I am using `PAYRATE` as a constant? I have tried messing around with the parens with no luck.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double PAYRATE = 20.00;

int main()
{
    double hoursWorked;
    double avgPayRate;

    cout << "Please Enter Hours Worked: " << endl;
    cin  >> hoursWorked;
    cout << endl;

    if (hoursWorked < 40)
    {
        avgPayRate = (hoursWorked * PAYRATE) / hoursWorked;
        cout << "Your Average Pay Rate is: " << avgPayRate << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        avgPayRate = (hoursWorked * PAYRATE) + (1.5 * PAYRATE)
                      * (hoursWorked - 40) / hoursWorked;
        cout << "Your Average Pay Rate is: " << avgPayRate << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you giving as input, what do you expect as output, and what do you actually get as output?

Comment: "_Why isn't this code able to output the average pay rate???_" What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am obviously brand new to c++ so thanks in advance for reading; but I am practicing and am expecting the end user to input hours worked and receive the 'average' pay rate. So if you work 2 hours @ 20 per hour and 1 hour was overtime @ 1.5 times 20; I am expecting to see the average rate but the output seems to reflect only the total wages earned.

Answer (score 1):

When the number of hours worked is above 40, I think your formula should be:

```
avgPayRate = ((40 * PAYRATE) + (1.5 * PAYRATE) * (hoursWorked - 40)) / hoursWorked;
```

Because you work 40 hours for the nominal PAYRATE, and the rest of them for 50% higher rate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if (hoursWorked < 40) {
    avgPayRate = PAYRATE;
}
else {
    avgPayRate = ((PAYRATE * 40) + (hoursWorked - 40) * PAYRATE * 1.5) / hoursWorked;
}

cout << "Your Average Pay Rate is: " << avgPayRate << endl;
```

No need for all those calculations when `hoursWorked < 40`.

---

It's also a good habit to put repeating values in a single place (in case they change, you'll only need to edit one, and this will be less error prone):

```
int main()
{
    double hoursWorked;
    double avgPayRate;
    const double PAYRATE = 20.00;
    const double normalHours = 40.0;
    const double factor = 1.5;

    cout << "Please Enter Hours Worked: ";
    cin  >> hoursWorked;
    cout << endl;

    if (hoursWorked < normalHours) {
        avgPayRate = PAYRATE;
    }
    else {
        avgPayRate = ((PAYRATE * normalHours)
                     + (hoursWorked - normalHours) * PAYRATE * factor) / hoursWorked;
    }

    cout << "Your Average Pay Rate is: " << avgPayRate << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The calculations are needed for more than 40 hours because it is the base rate plus 1.5 times the rate for hours over 40. The average will be somewhere between 1 and 1.5 times the base rate.

Comment: @Kevin - Updated, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just reading about ternary operator, the second method seems like a lot less code and easier to read, is this operator generally preferred over if else loops?

Comment: @sourceMode - The ternary operator is somewhat shorter, but it doesn't make a difference for the resulting code. (but I removed that example, because there was some more calculation needed for bonus for hours only above 40).

Comment: `avgPayRate = (PAYRATE * 40) + (hoursWorked - 40) * PAYRATE * 1.5;` will not give the average payrate.  You need to divide the whole thing by the number of hours worked.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Err, yes - thanks (tested it, but overlooked it..)